# Error: Unable to initialize main class Car Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: string

Tags: java

What might be the problem? I am stuck and do not know how to continue as I try to figure this out. Any help, direction, and explanation would be very much appreciated!

This is what I should do:
Design appropriate accessor methods to get the values stored in an object’s yearModel, make, and speed fields.
The accelerate method should add 5 to the speed field each time it’s called.
The brake method should subtract 5 from the speed field each time it’s called.

```
public class Car {
    private int yearModel;
    private string make;
    private int speed;

    public Car() {
        this.yearModel = 2015;
        this.make = "Tesla";
        this.speed = 40;
    }

    // Constructor
    public Car(int yearModel, string make, int speed) {
        this.yearModel = yearModel;
        this.make = make;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    // Getters
    public int getYearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }
    public string getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    // Setters
    public void accelerate() {
        speed += 5;
    }
    public void brake() {
        speed -= 5;
    }

    public string toString() {
        return "Car: " + yearModel + " " + make + " " + speed;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        System.out.println(myCar);
        myCar.accelerate();
        System.out.println(myCar);
        myCar.brake();
        System.out.println(myCar);
        Car myCar2 = new Car(2015, "Tesla", 40);
        System.out.println(myCar2);
    }
}
```

```
After running the java program, this is the error I get:
Error: Unable to initialize main class Car
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: string
```

Comment: How did you manage to compile this code with those erroneous references to `string`? You must have created your own `string` class and removed it after compiling `Car`… Well, actually that still wouldn’t compile, as `new Car(2015, "Tesla", 40)` doesn’t match the `Car(int yearModel, string make, int speed)` constructor.

Comment: ECJ allows partial compilation with errors. That might be how op managed to compile it,

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in line 3. `string` should have a capital S, so `String` instead.

Same then goes for the getter `public string getMake` and the toString()-method and the argument for make in the constructor which all need a capital S again.